# navigation menu-open does not close after clicking one of the elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I a, trying to deploy my first website. Unfortunately I have a problem with my navigation on mobile devices. I made a hamburger but the menu doesnt close after i click on one of nav element.The problem is when i click o one of the elements from nav. Then i can see that the website scrolls down but the menu is still open i dont see anything else. Could any of you take a look. Thanks

```js
let navigation = document.getElementById('nav');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let scrollYPosition = window.pageYOffset;

  if (scrollYPosition > 50) {
    navigation.classList.add('move');
  } else {
    navigation.classList.remove('move');
  }

})


let hamburger = document.getElementById('hamburger-js');

hamburger.addEventListener('click', function() {
  hamburger.classList.toggle('open')
  navigation.classList.toggle('menu-open')
})
```

```css
.navigation {
  padding: 0 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 300;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  &.menu-open {
    background-color: $mainColor;
    .logo {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 5;
      .logo-black {
        display: block;
      }
      .logo-light {
        display: none;
      }
    }
    .hamburger {
      span {
        background-color: $secondaryColor;
      }
    }
    ul {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100vw;
      left: 0;
      padding: 50px 0 0 0;
      height: 100vh;
      top: 0;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: $mainColor;
      backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
      li {
        margin: 0 0 15px 0;
        &:last-child {
          margin: 0;
        }
        a {
          padding: 0;
          color: $secondaryColor;
          font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  &.move {
    background-color: rgba($mainColor, $alpha: 0.9);
    transition: 0.5s;
    .logo {
      .logo-black {
        display: block;
      }
      .logo-light {
        display: none;
      }
    }
    ul {
      li {
        a {
          color: $secondaryColor;
          font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
          text-decoration: none;
          &:hover {
            color: rgb(66, 66, 66);
            font-weight: 600;
            transform: scale(1.2);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    .hamburger {
      span {
        background-color: $secondaryColor;
      }
    }
  }
  .logo {
    .logo-black {
      display: none;
    }
    a {
      padding-top: 4px;
      display: inline-block;
      img {
        display: block;
        width: 80px;
      }
    }
  }
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    @media(max-width: 1000px) {
      display: none;
    }
    li {
      margin-right: 20px;
      &:last-child {
        margin-right: 0;
      }
      a {
        color: #ffffff;
        padding: 30px 15px;
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
        font-size: 28px;
        // color: #EF67A7;
        text-decoration: none;
        &:hover {
          font-weight: 600;
          color: #EF67A7;
          transform: scale(1.2);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  .hamburger {
    padding: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 24px;
    position: relative;
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    @media(max-width: 1000px) {
      display: block;
    }
    span {
      height: 4px;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: $mainColor;
      border-radius: 4px;
      &:nth-of-type(1) {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
      }
      &:nth-of-type(2) {
        top: 50%;
        left: 0;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
      }
      &:nth-of-type(3) {
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
      }
    }
    &.open {
      span {
        &:nth-of-type(2) {
          display: none;
        }
        &:nth-of-type(1) {
          top: 7px;
          transform: rotate(45deg);
        }
        &:nth-of-type(3) {
          top: 7px;
          transform: rotate(135deg);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav" class="navigation">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="index.html#main">
      <img class="logo-black" src="assets/img/Logo_wektor.svg" alt="">
      <img class="logo-light" src="assets/img/Logo_wektor.svg" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>

  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#main"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#about" style="scroll-behavior: smooth;">O Nas</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#offer">Oferta</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#contact">Kontakt</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button class="hamburger" id="hamburger-js">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </button>

</nav>
```

Probably there is a problem with JS but i do not really now it yet, just begining. Maybe you can notice what is wrong with the code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something with `document.getElementById(<ID>).style.display = 'block'` (show) and `'none'` for hide?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your JS is working. You haven't placed the button properly, it's getting out of view port and looks as if it is hidden. I added some margin to the `.hamburger` class and voila!

SCSS:

```
$mainColor: red;
$secondaryColor: blue;
.navigation {
  padding: 0 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 300;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  &.menu-open {
    background-color: $mainColor;
    .logo {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 5;
      .logo-black {
        display: block;
      }
      .logo-light {
        display: none;
      }
    }
    .hamburger {
      span {
        background-color: $secondaryColor;
      }
    }
    ul {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100vw;
      left: 0;
      padding: 50px 0 0 0;
      height: 100vh;
      top: 0;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: $mainColor;
      backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
      li {
        margin: 0 0 15px 0;
        &:last-child {
          margin: 0;
        }
        a {
          padding: 0;
          color: $secondaryColor;
          font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  &.move {
    background-color: rgba($mainColor, $alpha: 0.9);
    transition: 0.5s;
    .logo {
      .logo-black {
        display: block;
      }
      .logo-light {
        display: none;
      }
    }
    ul {
      li {
        a {
          color: $secondaryColor;
          font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
          text-decoration: none;
          &:hover {
            color: rgb(66, 66, 66);
            font-weight: 600;
            transform: scale(1.2);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    .hamburger {
      span {
        background-color: $secondaryColor;
      }
    }
  }
  .logo {
    .logo-black {
      display: none;
    }
    a {
      padding-top: 4px;
      display: inline-block;
      img {
        display: block;
        width: 80px;
      }
    }
  }
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    @media(max-width: 1000px) {
      display: none;
    }
    li {
      margin-right: 20px;
      &:last-child {
        margin-right: 0;
      }
      a {
        color: #ffffff;
        padding: 30px 15px;
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
        font-size: 28px;
        // color: #EF67A7;
        text-decoration: none;
        &:hover {
          font-weight: 600;
          color: #EF67A7;
          transform: scale(1.2);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  .hamburger {
    margin: 2.5em;
    padding: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 24px;
    position: relative;
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    @media(max-width: 1000px) {
      display: block;
    }
    span {
      height: 4px;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: $mainColor;
      border-radius: 4px;
      &:nth-of-type(1) {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
      }
      &:nth-of-type(2) {
        top: 50%;
        left: 0;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
      }
      &:nth-of-type(3) {
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
      }
    }
    &.open {
      span {
        &:nth-of-type(2) {
          display: none;
        }
        &:nth-of-type(1) {
          top: 7px;
          transform: rotate(45deg);
        }
        &:nth-of-type(3) {
          top: 7px;
          transform: rotate(135deg);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. They problem is when i click o one of the elements from nav. Then i can see that the website scrolls down but the menu is still open i dont see anything else.